# Infinite Sum of products

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

What is the infinite sum

$$S = {1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1\cdot 3}{3\cdot 6} + \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{3\cdot 6\cdot 9}+ ....}?$$
I attempted messing around with the $n$ th term in the series but didnt see any solution.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your general term is

$$a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{6^n(n!)^2}$$

But you may know that, for $|x|<1$,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2} x^n$$

Now, take $x=2/3$, then your sum is $\sqrt{3}$.

---

In case you don't know already the development of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$, you can use the more general [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:
$n^{th}$ term is $$\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{3^n\cdot n!}$$
$$=\frac{2^n\cdot n!\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{6^n\cdot n!\cdot n!}$$
$$=\frac{2n!}{6^n\cdot n!\cdot n!}$$
$$=\frac{^{2n}C_n}{6^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

The $n+1$ th term is $$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2n-1) }{3^{n}(n)!}=\frac{(2n)!}{6^{n}(n!)^2}$$ Hence the series is $$\lim_{x\to 1/6}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}{n}x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4/6}}=\sqrt{{3}}$$ This type of sum appears while calculating probability of return to origin in $1D$ [random walks](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter12.pdf).